# Reading Automation type information with WMI

Tags: com, activex, wmi

I know it is possible to use the [Win32_ProgIDSpecification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg196677(v=vs.85).aspx) to iterate over the ProgIDs available on the system.

Is there anything in WMI that allows iterating over a given ProgID and returning type information -- methods and their parameters and return types, properties and their return types, and events?

(I am looking to create a tool to generate TypeScript definitions for Automation objects, given a specific ProgID. At this point, I am using .NET reflection on types referenced in a C# project.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the WMI doesn't provide such info, instead you must use the [`ITypeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221696.aspx) Interface to retrieve that type information.